# Store value of a signal and store as constant value in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is it possible to get the value of a signal at a particular instant and store as a constant value for use somewhere else in the model?

Answer (score 3):

One way I like to do this is to use a [Triggered Subsystem](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/triggered-subsystems.html).  The actual subsytem can consist simply of the inport connected directly to the outport. Connect the signal you're interested in to the inport; and use whatever signal you want as the trigger.  When you've triggered the subsystem, the input at that time becomes the output, and is held there until you trigger the subsystem again.

Comment: Wow.. What a brilliant and easy solution. I'm enlightened! :)

Comment: You don't need to do anything with "states when enabling", as you have no states in the subsystem (and even if you do, they are always held - unlike in an enabled subsytem).  What is important is that the output is held, which is the default (and only implemented) behaviour.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Thanks for pointing that out.  I had merged those features of triggered vs enabled subsystems in my mind.  I edited my answer to avoid confusing future readers.